# Are these my Leaks?

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments, memory-leaks

When I profile my app in Instruments 4.3, I get a bunch of leaks. Some are as small as 32 bytes and others are a few hundred bytes. So far it seems to me as if these are not my leaks because it does not point anywhere to my source code.

Anyway here is an image of ALL the leaks:

[image]

Does anyone know what these leaks are and if I need to be worried about these?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that these are not my leaks after googling around a bit. They are just leaks UIKit and QuartzCore. So there is nothing wrong on my end! :)

Answer (score 1):

Open your Project in XCode. Push and Hold "Run", it will open a Tap, then click on "Analyse". This will point your leaks in the Code

Hope this helps

Comment: I found the leaks, I am not looking for them. Im talking about those leaks above specifically.